# How do I know if my page is being cached?

Tags: caching, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that is doing a few weird things, and I believe it is because it is being cached. I changed the contents of a CSS stylesheet file, and the change took around 10 minutes before it appeared live.

I can't however find any caching mechanism setup. I've looked through cPanel and can't see anything setup there. The IP of the site resolves to the IP that cPanel is showing.

I've looked for plugins in WordPress and can't see any caching plugins (although if it was a caching plugin, would accessing a stylesheet be cached?).

Any tips on how I can see if the page is being cached on the server or by a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Put a JavaScript bug on the page which crafts a random URL and requests it. Compare the number of page requests to random URL requests. But there are lots of scenarios where a browser can cache a page in the absence of caching information.

Answer (score -1):

If your website is behind Cloud Flare network or such, this is normal behavior.

 Try running next command (Windows Command prompt/Linux terminal):

```
ping www.yoursite.com
```

and visit resolved IP address in browser - this may tell you if you are behind caching network.

Take a look at this article: http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: erm, no, Cloudflare and CDNs have nothing to do with what is happenning here, and that page you linked is not a very good source - the information is incomplete and some of it plain wrong. Although it only addresses conventional HTTP caching (as does the article above) Mark Nottingham's Caching Tutorial is a lot better - https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/